# settings,jsonc error, I have no idea what the error is about I was switching from python 2 to 3 from a yt tutorial

Tags: python

I have just started using visual studio and I was switching from python 2 to 3 on mac from a youtube tutorial and I have run across this error quite a lot, "Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again." The error is on settings.json. I just started python on this so please forgive me if this is a simple question. I've got no idea what to do, I tried reinstalling it, opening a new file.

Here is where the error occurs, the javascript is underlined in red and it says
"Colon expected jsonc(515) View Problem (⌥F8) No quick fixes available". there's a bunch of stuff before and after this but I've typed where the error occurs. [here's a screenshot][1]
[here's a second one][2]

code:

'''

```
{
"workbench.editorAssociations": [
    {
        "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
        "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
    }
],
"window.zoomLevel": 2,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
"python.pythonPath": "code-runner",
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "code-runner.executorMap"

    "javascript": "node",
    "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "php": "php",
    "python": "python3",
    "perl": "perl",
    "perl6": "perl6",
    "ruby": "ruby",
    "go": "go run",
    "lua": "lua",
    "groovy": "groovy",
    "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
    "bat": "cmd /c",
    "shellscript": "bash",
    "fsharp": "fsi",
    "csharp": "scriptcs",
    "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
    "typescript": "ts-node",
    "coffeescript": "coffee",
    "scala": "scala",
    "swift": "swift",
    "julia": "julia",
    "crystal": "crystal",
    "ocaml": "ocaml",
    "r": "Rscript",
    "applescript": "osascript",
    "clojure": "lein exec",
    "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "racket": "racket",
    "scheme": "csi -script",
    "ahk": "autohotkey",
    "autoit": "autoit3",
    "dart": "dart",
    "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "haskell": "runhaskell",
    "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
    "lisp": "sbcl --script",
    "kit": "kitc --run",
    "v": "v run",
    "sass": "sass --style expanded",
    "scss": "scss --style expanded",
    "less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
    "FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
}
```

}

Comment: There must be something before that.  Show is the whole file, or at least some lines before the error.  That's where the problem is.

Comment: From that message you posted about “Colon expected”, do you think there might be a missing colon somewhere in your settings file? If you notice something not matching the pattern “key”: “value” in your settings file, maybe that relates to this issue.

Comment: I don’t really think so because it said one error and it was highlighted, is there a way to reset everything to default i tried reinstalling and nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have entered in code-runner executor map twice.

replace

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "code-runner.executorMap"


    "javascript": "node",
    "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "php": "php",
    "python": "python3 -u",
    "perl": "perl",
    "perl6": "perl6",
    "ruby": "ruby",
    "go": "go run",
    "lua": "lua",
    "groovy": "groovy",
    "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
    "bat": "cmd /c",
    "shellscript": "bash",
    "fsharp": "fsi",
    "csharp": "scriptcs",
    "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
    "typescript": "ts-node",
    "coffeescript": "coffee",
    "scala": "scala",
    "swift": "swift",
    "julia": "julia",
    "crystal": "crystal",
    "ocaml": "ocaml",
    "r": "Rscript",
    "applescript": "osascript",
    "clojure": "lein exec",
    "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "racket": "racket",
    "scheme": "csi -script",
    "ahk": "autohotkey",
    "autoit": "autoit3",
    "dart": "dart",
    "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "haskell": "runhaskell",
    "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
    "lisp": "sbcl --script",
    "kit": "kitc --run",
    "v": "v run",
    "sass": "sass --style expanded",
    "scss": "scss --style expanded",
    "less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
    "FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
}
```

with

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "javascript": "node",
    "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "php": "php",
    "python": "python3 -u",
    "perl": "perl",
    "perl6": "perl6",
    "ruby": "ruby",
    "go": "go run",
    "lua": "lua",
    "groovy": "groovy",
    "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
    "bat": "cmd /c",
    "shellscript": "bash",
    "fsharp": "fsi",
    "csharp": "scriptcs",
    "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
    "typescript": "ts-node",
    "coffeescript": "coffee",
    "scala": "scala",
    "swift": "swift",
    "julia": "julia",
    "crystal": "crystal",
    "ocaml": "ocaml",
    "r": "Rscript",
    "applescript": "osascript",
    "clojure": "lein exec",
    "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "racket": "racket",
    "scheme": "csi -script",
    "ahk": "autohotkey",
    "autoit": "autoit3",
    "dart": "dart",
    "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "haskell": "runhaskell",
    "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
    "lisp": "sbcl --script",
    "kit": "kitc --run",
    "v": "v run",
    "sass": "sass --style expanded",
    "scss": "scss --style expanded",
    "less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
    "FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
}
```

Comment: I'll edit the post and include the full code

Comment: I just added the full code, I wrote it exactly like this "javascript": "node",

Comment: the javascript node was meant to be an example.
the problem is that you have entered code-runner.executormap twice when you only need it once.
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "code-runner.executorMap"
replace with
"code-runner.executorMap": {

Comment: I just replaced it still getting the same error here's the code:                                 fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
    }            It now says Expected comma or closing brace with the bracket at the end

Comment: Is there a way to reset everything to default there's nothing important on it. I tried reinstalling and nothing happened